# How do I skip lines when I'm reading from a text file?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm reading from a text file which looks like this:

```
1
The Adventures of Tom Sawyer
2
Huckleberry Finn    
4    
The Sword in the Stone    
6  
Stuart Little
```

I have to make it so that the user can enter the reference number and the program will perform binary and linear search and output the title. My teacher said to use two ArrayLists, one for the numbers and one for the titles, and output from them. I just can't figure out how to skip lines so I can add to the corresponding arraylist.

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(txtInputNumber.getText());
    ArrayList <String> books = new ArrayList <>();
    ArrayList <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList <> ();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bookList.txt"));
        String word;
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null ){
            books.add(word);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help!

Comment: I Think that you need to skip empty lines, and process (process as an opposite to skip) the other lines. I think, that you had to do some parsing process. For example ask if the first word of the line is a number, you can assume that is number line, else process the line as Book tittle.

Comment: Why not add a little code inside of the while loop. You could perhaps flip a boolean variable from true to false, and write the appropriate list based on the booleans value. Lots of things you could try.

Comment: where are chapters 3 and 5?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou idk where the other chapters are, I just got that file to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if you are in even or odd lines by doing a *modulo 2* operation on the line number:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bookList.txt"))) {
    String word;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while ((word = br.readLine()) != null ){
        if (++lineCount % 2 == 0) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(word));
        } else {
            books.add(word);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(txtInputNumber.getText());
ArrayList <String> books = new ArrayList <>();
ArrayList <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList <> ();
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bookList.txt"));
    String word;
    while ((word = br.readLine()) != null ){
            numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(word));   
            word = br.readLine()
            books.add(word);
    }


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make check to see if it is actually a integer, that you read from the file. As far as I remember, there is no built in method to do this, but you can define your own as:

```
boolean tryParseInt(String value) {  
    try {  
        Integer.parseInt(value);  
        return true;  
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Then just make a check to see if the line you have read in is a integer or not.

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(txtInputNumber.getText());
ArrayList <String> books = new ArrayList <>();
ArrayList <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList <> ();
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bookList.txt"));
    String word;

    while ((word = br.readLine()) != null ){
        if (tryParseInt(word))
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(word))
        else
            books.add(word);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this help!